# JS hide and show div, save after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have few big blocks in my website.
Some users want to hide these blocks.

I Succeed to hide the block by pressing a button, but its not saved after refresh.

How can I do that?
let the users hide and show the blocks and it will save after refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remember the state of the blocks either client side (in a [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) or using web [local storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)) or server-side (settings stored on your server for your users). Then either when rendering your page on the server (if you stored the setting on the server) or when the page loads (if it's on the client), you show or hide the blocks according to the setting.

Client-side, local storage is much easier to deal with than cookies, and is [well-supported by modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage). If you want to do this client-side, here's an example using local storage: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ULiMeDI/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ULiMeDI/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" checked> Show box1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked> Show box2</label>
  <div id="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box2">Box 2</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var showing;
      showing = JSON.parse(localStorage.showing || "null");
      if (!showing) {
        showing = {
          box1: true,
          box2: true
        };
      }
      else {
        showBox(1, showing.box1);
        showBox(2, showing.box2);
      }

      document.getElementById("chk1").onclick =
        document.getElementById("chk2").onclick =
          cbclicked;

      function cbclicked() {
        var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var box = "box" + num;
        showing[box] = !showing[box];
        showBox(num, showing[box]);
        localStorage.showing = JSON.stringify(showing);
      }      

      function showBox(num, flag) {
        document.getElementById("chk" + num).checked = flag;
        document.getElementById("box" + num).style.display =
          flag ? "block" : "none";
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously that's very off-the-cuff and I don't recommend using `.onclick` properties and such, but I didn't want to get into cross-browser issues around proper even hookup and it's just a quick example.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just setup the code on my site and its works great.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the state you should use either a database or a cookies. The easier way is cookies.   When a user hides a block you should save the block #id in your cookie and then in your php code you need to handle it, meaning: reading the cookie value and hiding the blocks the user choose to hide.

Comment: hey, i have never used cookies before, you have maybe example code that can i use?

Comment: You should use google: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [$.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) plugin

This will save the toggle state.

```
if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open'){    
    $('#box1').slideDown('fast');
} else {
    $('#box1').slideUp('fast');
}

// Toggle Panel and Set Cookie //
$('#box').click(function(){        
    $('#box1').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            $.cookie('panel', 'closed');
        } else {
            $.cookie('panel', 'open');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's an live exmaple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/510/)